# How to exclude field from cache in drupal?

Tags: caching, drupal, field

How can I exclude field from caching not excluding page from being cached? Field value is modified using `_preprocess_field` hook depending on cookie variable. Cache system caches the entire page and `mymodule_preprocess_field` never called to change the field value. 
Any ideas how to exclude this field from caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal page cache caches entire page.  If you want a small part of data to update, such as user login or up to the date stock prices, you should use ajax, and on the page that's returning ajax set it to not cache.